# How to remove tableview from page scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I had BillPreviewController (page scrollview) that contain many bills, and `BillViewController(tableView)` that has many items. This is the code that I use to create tableview in page scrollview.

I don't know how to remove it !

```
-(void)configureBillViewControllers{
self.billViewControllerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Bill *aBill in self.billArray) {

    BillViewController *abvc = [[BillViewController alloc] initWithBill:aBill];

    abvc.onDidSelectRowCallBack = ^(UINavigationController *nav){
        BillViewController *bvc = [self.billViewControllerArray objectAtIndex:pageControl.currentPage];
        Bill *newBill = [bvc bill];
        Item *anItem = [[newBill listOfOrderedItem] objectAtIndex:bvc.selectedItemIndex];

        UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:[anItem name] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Remove" otherButtonTitles:@"Edit", nil];
        [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.toolbar];

        self.totalBillDollarLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", [newBill getTotalPrice]];
        self.totalBillRielLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [newBill getTotalPrice]*self.anExchange.rielBuyPerDollar];
    };
    abvc.delegate = self;

    [self.billViewControllerArray addObject:abvc];       

}
}
```

Comment: You can use "removeFromSuperview"

Comment: Inside the method where you want to remove the tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try,

```
 self.billViewControllerArray=nil;
```

use this where you want to remove....